# What is the best charging strategy for a macbook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, charging

I heard several strategy about macbook power supply connection:

- keeping alway at least 50% of battery level
- let unplugged until reaching the 10% warning
- perform once a month a full discharge

What is the best strategy to keep the battery performant on the long run? I suppose it involve some physical battery notion but also how *OSX* handle the battery management at the software level.

Comment: Apple already has several Support pages regarding getting the most from your Mac battery.  Have you looked at those already?

Comment: Yes there is this page which give some interesting tips but doesn't answer to my question about plug/unplug the power supply: https://www.apple.com/lae/batteries/maximizing-performance/

Comment: These days, there is very little managing to do... batteries don't have a "battery memory" like they used to. Laptop batteries are good for a number of cycles, and as long as they're plugged in, they're not using up one of those cycles. So if you can plug it in while you're using it, do so; if you can't, minimise the amount of power you're using in the usual ways (closing apps you're not using, reducing screen brightness, etc.)